# How do I open this Android project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock

I have it cloned on my PC, and I tried to create a new project from existing source. I pointed it to the code I downloaded, but I had bunches of errors. I went into the project properties, and set the build target to Google API (8), and that fixed a lot of the errors, but I can't fix the remaining errors. This is my first time importing a project from github into Eclipse, so I am probably missing some simple fundamental steps.

Edit: adding error listing
I am down to 9 errors (some are dupes)

`ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED cannot be resolved or is not a field in Alarms.java`

`Cannot instantiate the type Vibrator in AlarmKlaxon.java`

`com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable in AlarmKlaxon.java and SetAlarm.java`

`mContext cannot be resolved in DigitalClock.java` (x5)

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing what errors you're getting.

Comment: Good point :) OP Edited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhy in the project.properties the target was android-3 (target=android-3), write it to target=android-8, because a lot of layout xmls are using match parent. Then clean the project (Eclipse->Project->Clean...)
After this, no more xml errors will be there, but some java code errors remain, which are from  use of com.android.internal.R which is a hidden android api? 
This explains the use of it:
http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/using-com-android-internal-part-5-summary-and-example/

Comment: That was it. Thanks. I would have never figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

> File -> import... -> existing projects into workspace -> select project

Comment: That gives an error "No projects are found to import". I believe this is because there is no .project file in the package?

Comment: @MrGibbage that is probably the case. Have you tried creating a new project, and just copying in the resources and source code?

Comment: Thanks, Phil. Yes, I tried that and I still got lots of errors (even more than what I have now). I didn't think it would be that hard, so I was pretty sure I was just doing it wrong. @abbath below commented that it looks like this project is using some hidden api's. That seems to be on track so I am looking into that now.